# overloading Ruby's [...] Array creation shorthand

Tags: ruby, arrays, overloading, method-chaining, shorthand

I've written a library that extends several base Ruby classes with observing wrappers mostly through method aliasing. However, I've hit a roadblock with the Array instantiation shorthand (e.g. `@a = [1, 2, 3]` )  I can't seem to find any method that's actually called in the creation of an Array object by the shorthand means. It's not an inherited `#[]` method in the current scope or inherited from any class or module in the ancestors chain. I've also overloaded or watched every method from the class's `#new` to an instance's `#initialize` to the singleton_method `#[]` on the Array class object based on the Ruby C code

```
rb_define_singleton_method(rb_cArray, "[]", rb_ary_s_create, -1);
```

Does anyone know how I can assign a method that would be within the method chain of the shorthand Array instance instantiation?

Comment: So #initialize is never invoked when you use the array literal Syntax? o_O  At least in ruby 1.9.3 it is for me (if I overload Array#initialize in ruby).

Comment: I just upgraded to 1.9.3 and am still not having my overloading #initialize called

Comment: Did you try it with Pure ruby (i.e. not in the C extension)?  It's working for me. `chris@chris:~/flippa/rails$ pry
pry(main)> class Array
pry(main)*   def initialize(*)
pry(main)*     puts "Got here"
pry(main)*   end
pry(main)* end
Got here
=> nil
pry(main)> []
Got here
=> []
pry(main)> `

Comment: Okey, lets see… It **works** in pry, _doesn't_ in IRB, _doesn't_ via ruby directly  `ruby -e 'class Array; def initialize(*); puts "Got here" ; end ; end; a=[]' `

Comment: Ah, weird. I guess pry overrides some core classes o_O

Comment: @d11wtq, see my comment below (buried under someone's tangent) about why pry is being (kinda improperly) successful

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, like pretty much every other programming language on the planet, Ruby does not allow overloading of literals. If you require literal overloading, you will have to use one of the few programming languages which support it, like [Ioke](http://Ioke.Org/) or [Seph](http://Seph-Lang.Org/).

Here's an example in Ioke:

```
[] = method(foo, foo println)
[1]
; 1
```

And in Seph:

```
[] = #(foo, foo println)
[1]
; 1
```

[Note that these will, of course, wreak havoc with your system, since, for example, a large part of the Ioke/Seph standard library is implemented in Ioke/Seph, and they use lists all over the place, so in a production system, you'll want to properly encapsulate this.]

Comment: Upvoting this answer, but see the suggestion to use #initialize above.

Comment: @Jörg As I'd stated, I'm not trying to overload the literal, I'm trying to overload what its calling to instantiate an Array object. Which with Ruby being a remarkably open and tweakable programming language should be right up its alley. As others thought too, it should be no more complicated than overloading #initialize; but that doesn't work outside of pry, it'd seem (which seems to be manually parsing and programmatically calling Array.new itself via coderay, instead of using the standard ruby1.9.x interpreter)